# How to get analysis result faster using Partition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012, which has these 2 columns:

```
Date, Amount
```

I want to get the summary of a month, i.e. for May 2013. And I also want to get the summary of last month, the same month last year, and average of past 12 month. I know I can use GROUP BY to get the data for each month, then get all the data I need. However, the table has so many rows, I want to make it faster.

One possibility is to use Partition By

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), SUM(Amount) OVER (Partiotion By YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date))
FROM myTable
```

However, how can I use this to get data like: last month, same month last year, and average of past 12 month?

Or, I need to use partition by to get monthly data, and then use ROWS to get them?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to first aggregate the data in a subquery or CTE.  Then you can express the conditions you want using window functions:

```
SELECT yr, mon, amount,
       LAG(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY yr*100+mon) as LastMonth,
       LAG(Amount, 12) OVER (ORDER BY yr*100+mon) as LastYearMonth,
       AVG(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY yr*100 + mon RANGE BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM (SELECT YEAR(Date) as yr, MONTH(Date) as mon, SUM(Amount) as Amount
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY  YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
     ) ym;
```

Comment: May lead to less reading if you add a `WHERE` clause to your derived table? (+1 though)